# SaltStack: conditional include: Error if empty

Tags: salt-stack

I have a conditional include which looks like this:

```
include:
{% if CONDITION-A %}
  - foo.bar
{% endif %}
{% if CONDITION-B %}
  - blu.bla
{% endif %}
```

This works in most cases.

But it fails if CONDITION-A and CONDITION-B are false.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this pattern now:

```
include:
  - dummy
{% if CONDITION-A %}
  - foo.bar
{% endif %}
{% if CONDITION-B %}
  - blu.bla
{% endif %}
```

dummy.sls:

```
dummy-no-op:
  test.nop
```

Not nice, but works.

Better (simpler, more obvious) answers are welcome.

[Docs for test.nop](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.test.html#salt.states.test.nop)

Answer (score 1):

This is also ugly, but you could wrap the entire include block in an if condtion that check if either `CONDITION-A` or `CONDITION-B` is true:

```
{% if CONDITION-A or CONDITION-B %}
include:
  {% if CONDITION-A %}
  - foo.bar
  {% endif %}
  {% if CONDITION-B %}
  - blu.bla
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This way jinja will remove the include block if both conditions are false